# Call wrapper function from inside jQuery AJAX complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is what I'm attempting to do, but I'm getting an error that I can't bind to undefined, I assume because I'm in an anonymous function. I need to access the method (`getAndSayHi`) the AJAX call is in.

```
var Parent() = new Function () {
    this.sayHi = function (name) {
        console.log("hello " + name);
    }
    this.getAndSayHi = function () {
        $.ajax({
            ....
            success: function(data) {
                this.sayHi.bind(this, data);
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
this.getAndSayHi = function () {
    var parent = this;
    $.ajax({
        ....
        success: function(data) {
            parent.sayHi.bind(this, data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you might explain why: `this` always refers to the current object instance. Within the success function, `this` refers to the jQuery object, not to your `Parent` object. Thus, the called method is undefined.